# How to Split row into multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

[image: problem]

Hi can somebody help me, i have some question on how to separate this row into columns with the same id number. I have tried some SQL function like `GROUP_CONCAT()` or `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function but i dont know how it works

[image: Output]

I want the output to look something like this

Comment: please post your sample as formatted text inside your question (do not use images, pls)

Comment: This question is different from the one linked to and claimed to 'already has an answer'. This deals with one initial table, while they other has several initial tables. That calls for different approaches when tackling them.

Answer (score 2):

It should resolve your problem:

```
INSERT INTO output SELECT
    input.ID,
    MIN(input.Unit_Cost),
    MAX(input.Unit_Cost)
FROM input
GROUP BY input.ID
```

Comment: Does this require creating the `field list` for `output` beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

You might try a pivot table query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.`Unit_Cost` as `Unit_Cost1`,
    ifnull(t2.`Unit_Cost`,'') as `Unit_Cost2`
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2
ON t1.`ID` = t2.`ID`
GROUP BY `ID`
ORDER BY `ID`
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't separate it to columns, because then you could theoreticaly have infinite number of columns when the `ID` would be the same for infinite number of rows. But you can make `GROUP_CONCACT()` as you suggested and then separate the values in application with for example `split()` function.

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(Unit_Cost SEPARATOR ';') Unit_Cost
FROM CostTable
GROUP BY ID
```

[Here are more examples](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) with `GROUP_CONCAT()`